# determine when to call a method using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a variable set as such:

```
var lastId = null
```

I only need to call my GetApproval method, once, so I've tried to control it like so:

```
if(lastId != currentId)
{
  GetAppoval(currentId);
  lastId = currentId;
```

}

However, placing an alert between GetApproval and lastId assignment reveals, that the are the same everytime this code is hit, therefore resulting in the call being made to GetApproval everytime.

Why is this?

***EDIT***

Sorry - GetApproval is a void method, which calls a c# WebMethod to populate a div

***EDIT***
GetApprovalMethod:

```
function GetApproval(messageId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/GetApproval",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ messageId: messageId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr) {

                    var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                    if (xhr.status === 401 && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("text/html") >= 0) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                success: function (msg) {

                    $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                        $('#approvaltmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#results');
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: What is `GetAppoval()` method? Could you provide relevant code? BTW, isn't it `GetApproval()` ?

Comment: there is a ) after currentId

Comment: So looks like an async method. You have to post relevant code otherwise i don't think you can get any accurate answer... And provide more cotext of already posted code. What is the scope of each variables. Your question really lacks sufficent infos.

Comment: If this method is calling on `click` event, what about to use [JavaScript .one() event](http://api.jquery.com/one/) then?

Comment: Well, if they are always the same, doesn't that imply that there is an error in the currentId? How are you getting currentId?

Comment: the currentId can be the same, I have a grid with a button, that can be fired multiple times. @Pavlo, i like only being able to click the button once, do you have any examples? if so, post as answer, so i can award if it works

Comment: @CSharpNewBee so you won't post any more relevant code, that's ok with me, GL!

Comment: What is the behaviour of `GetApproval()`

Comment: As I mentioned above, to use [JavaScript .one() event](http://api.jquery.com/one/). Examples are there. Is that what you needed?

Comment: @A.Wolff i'll assume the -1 is from you - wow, give a man chance if it was, I was at the door!

Comment: @CSharpNewBee you get it, one more chance! ;) Now, how your code is supposed to update currentId value? Where do you set it following server response? Are your server at least returning anything supposed to update this value?

Comment: Also, possible solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738859/how-to-call-ajax-only-once

Comment: @A.Wolff - cheers :-). the click button, does several things 1. it collects message details, approval details etc, which are populated in tabs. the Approval details are using the Jquery templates, to display the information. I need to prevent the approval method from being called everytime, as it increments the approval content.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Replace the below code and check
> ```

```
if(lastId != currentId)
{
  currentId = GetAppoval(currentId);
  lastId = currentId;
}
```

Comment: not tried it yet, but this assumes, that GetApproval is returning a value, it doesnt. it just calls a webmethod to populate a div.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so ended up calling $('#results').empty(); before each call to the GetApproval method