# How do I make a Ajax call only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that fires when a user scrolls to the bottom of the screen. The only issue is that I would like for the Ajax call to fire only once. My code is:

```
        var w = $(window);
        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            if ($(document).height() - w.height() == w.scrollTop()) {


              $('#loading-image').show();
              $.ajax({
                    url: "page-2.html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                      $("#part2").html(result);
                      console.log();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                      $('#loading-image').hide();
                    }
              });


            }
        };
```

Comment: btw y do u need the ajax at the scroll bottom, may i know ?

Comment: @Riaz Laskar Yes, because I would like to load a file once the user scrolls to the bottom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call ajax only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738859/how-to-call-ajax-only-once)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way you can add a global variable and check it this way:

```
var w = $(window);
var BOTTOM_REACHED = false;
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ($(document).height() - w.height() == w.scrollTop() && !BOTTOM_REACHED) {
      BOTTOM_REACHED = true;
      $('#loading-image').show();
          $.ajax({
                url: "page-2.html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                  $("#part2").html(result);
                  console.log();
                },
                complete: function(){
                  $('#loading-image').hide();
                  BOTTOM_REACHED = false;
                }
          });


        }
    };
```

Comment: well, no, the *"simplest way"* would be to unbind the event after bottom is reached.

Comment: @KevinB, either you or me have misunderstood the question. There needs to be only one call to ajax, while scroll fires up to 100 times per second. What exactly do you mean about bottom reached?

Comment: Ok, then bind it again after loading the result, so you need to create another function and do some bind/unbind... Sure that was the simplest way :)

Comment: Once the ajax call happens, there's no reason for the event handler to exist. Why keep it?

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought he needed load another page every time scrolling to the bot of the content

Comment: Zakhar, No, @Kevin is not right. He is making assumptions. He assumes that function will no longer be used, based on nothing. He simply does not have that information. I can also assume this is a SPA, the variable will be reset when changing the page and the function will be used again. +1 from me, this is the correct answer to the question, considering the available info.

Comment: eh, no, i'm not assuming anything, i'm taking the question's requirements literally. If the ajax request is to only happen once, and the event handler's only purpose is to send the ajax request after a certain thing happens, then... there's no reason to have an event handler once it's done.

Comment: @KevinB, by deleting the function are you disabling functionality? The ability to reuse that function at a later point in the application's life? Yes or no. Where exactly in the question was that requested?

Comment: It wasn't not requested, It also wasn't requested to add a global var to the window.

Comment: @Kevin, I'm starting to like you. Completely off-topic, but we'd probably make sound apps together. Best regards! At Zakhar, please avoid "Thanks" comments. Up-ticking a comment you agree with is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this :

```
var bottom_reached = false;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
            bottom_reached = true;

              $('#loading-image').show();
             if(bottom_reached)
             {
               bottom_reached = false;
              $.ajax({
                    url: "page-2.html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                      $("#part2").html(result);
                      console.log();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                      $('#loading-image').hide();
                    }
              });

             }
            }
          });
```